# Is it acceptable to ask on SO about finding a job or internship?

Tags: discussion

Note: I'm NOT talking about actually searching for a job directly through a question post. (I obviously know about Careers on SO)

I just wanted to ask users about their own experience or advice. Such as:

- What kind of interview questions were asked?
- How they prepared for the interview?
- Extra qualifications or certifications that may help (i.e "Sun Certified")
- How college GPA/work experience can help or hurt your job search?
- etc.

Would this be an acceptable question to post on SO??

Comment: No. Off-topic :)

Comment: Nope. ---------

Answer (score 8):

No, this question would not be appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is only for programming-specific questions.